# Попадает ли точка в заштрихованную область

Tags: java

Вот [задача](https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=112169#1), к которой относится этот код, но он не работает,после вода переменных код не выполняет свою функцию, поэтому прошу вас, указать мои ошибки, а то я сам не могу их найти.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt ();
        int y = scan.nextInt ();
        if (y > 0 && x < 0 || y < 0 && x < 0 || y <= x) {                
            if (x*x + y*y <= 1) {
                System.out.println ("YES");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println ("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте «[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)» в справке. Сейчас в вопросе нет описания конкретной проблемы.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    double x = scan.nextDouble ();
    double y = scan.nextDouble ();

    boolean insideCircle = x * x + y * y <= 1;
    boolean onTheLeft = x <= 0;
    boolean onTopFunctionYequalsX = y >= x;

    boolean insideTheArea = insideCircle && (onTheLeft || onTopFunctionYequalsX);

    System.out.println(insideTheArea ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Comment: Распишите мне какие вы правила применяете

Comment: да что такое, подставьте в свой вариант x = 0.1 a y = 0.6 и проверьте что будет у вас, и что будет у меня. Как вы там что тестировали я не понимаю.

Comment: Достаточно этого: `insideCircle && (onTheLeft || onTopFunctionYequalsX)`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил